# How to configure Bolt browser to avoid error, "Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL 'ws://:7687' is invalid."

Tags: neo4j

Using Neo4j 3.3.0, which just self-upgraded tonight and suddenly the Bolt browser is giving the error:

> "Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL 'ws://:7687' is invalid."

when I do a simple test command of:

```
MATCH(n:Node) return n
```

It was working perfectly for weeks and I can't get back in as a result. I am using Flask and py2neo as well, but the problem manifests in the Bolt browser.

Was there a config that was overwritten?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you mean by 'Bolt browser'? By that do you mean the browser inside Neo4j desktop? Can you try typing ':server connect' and fill in 'bolt://localhost:7687' as the connection string?

Comment: The issue was fixed with an incremental update from Neo. The "just works out of box" aspect of the product had shielded me from these details.

Comment: In my case, this was because of a proxy connection that blocked my requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same issue. The issue seems to be only with the neo4j browser.

Open up your browser of choice .

go to http://localhost:7474/browser/

it works fine there. Possibly go through this for the reason https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/wiki/Neo4j-3.4-changelog

I hope they fix this soon.

Comment: This doesn't help for remote servers.